# Redshift: Selecting 'hardcoded value' as column_name + actual columns from tables in a union gives Assert code 1000?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the query below:

```
select
'display_campaign' as source,
client_id,
on_boarding_date
from same_schema.view_one

union all

select
'display creative' as source,
client_id,
on_boarding_date
from same_schema.view_two
```

Which yields the following error:

```
Error running query: Assert DETAIL: error: Assert code: 1000 context: col < m_num_colflds - col=13, m_num_colflds=2. query: 51556116 location: tbl_trans.hpp:468 process: padbmaster [pid=102659]
```

I think the issue is with the hardcoded columns because the error remains if I remove `client_id` and `on_boarding_date` (actual columns in both tables) from the query:

```
select
'display_campaign' as source
from same_schema.view_one

union all

select
'display creative' as source
from same_schema.view_two
```

Removing the `from` clause resolves the error. The following works fine:

```
select
'display_campaign' as source

union all

select
'display creative' as source
```

There's no column called `source` in either table. Any tips?

Comment: This is really strange and would surprise me.  Are you sure your queries are not overly simplified from what you are running?

Comment: I was mistaken, yes. Thanks for making me double check. The query hits two different views within the same schema, instead of two different tables each within a different schema. I'm not sure if that makes a difference. I updated the query.

Comment: But as far as the other mechanics, yes this is accurate. I can recreate the error even with just these narrow cases.

Comment: Are you sure that the issue isn't with one of your views?  If these are late binding views then definition errors won't show up until execution.

Comment: It looks like Redshift is saying that you are looking for column 13 where only 2 columns are defined.  col=13, m_num_colflds=2
It is throwing an error due to the column being referenced is out of bounds.  Since you are referencing views there is a lot more SQL in play than what is being provided.  Can you expand on the view definitions?

Comment: Are you sure that the underlying views are working. Could you provide some sample data from both views for debugging?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers yall. I spent time this morning making sure the views are working - pulling some reports and checking them against external sources. They're both individually queryable. A `select date from .... union select date from ...` yields the same error. So that points to something happening in the union. `select date from ....` works fine when run against either view. Both have a `date` column named `date`. The two views don't have identical schemas though (diff number of and diff columns). I'm not selecting all columns for the union (or any in my initial example) so idk.

Answer (score 0):

try to assign the same data type to hardcoded values explicitly like `'display_campaign'::text`, this error is for the data types mismatch which is not obvious with hardcoded lines (they seem to have unknown data type and unknown doesn't match unknown)